# Not Downloading Zip file in Vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, download, zip

I am trying to download a zip file from one directory in my machine. The zip file is already present in the folder. But when i use below code, no file is getting downloaded.

```
Protected Sub btn_CatIDownload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_CatIDownload.Click
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyFile.zip")
    Response.WriteFile("c:\Files\export\MyFile.zip")
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

There is no error when i run the code but no file is getting downloaded

Comment: Try it without the `Response.End()`. Also, `Response.TransmitFile` instead of `.WriteFile` hands off the operation to IIS, which can be more efficient. Consider writing a handler (.ashx) to send the file instead. And the account that the site is running under will need read permissions on the "C:\Files\export" directory.

Comment: Where is your download function?

Comment: @MarcoSadowski. This is the code behind of my download button click.

Comment: @Jeethu That don't answer my question. So you don't have a download function and you're wondering why nothing happens? Maybe you should check out how you can download files with the WebClient.

Comment: @MarcoSadowski : The OP appears to be using ASP.NET and thus is hosting a website with a download button somewhere on it. The VB.NET code in the question is the serverside code executed from a postback caused when the button is clicked in a client's web browser, which in this case is supposed to initiate a file download.

Comment: @VisualVincent ah thanks for the info. I thought this is for a desktop application

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to recreate the error. Your code works for me. I would say try adding a call to the Flush method before the Response.End():

```
Response.WriteFile("c:\Files\export\MyFile.zip")
Reponse.Flush()    
Response.End()
```

Or also try changing the MIME type to 'application/zip'

```
Response.ContentType = "application/zip"
```

If neither of those things work, there could be an issue if your file is too big to download this way. Check VB's ASP max file size restrictions. You should be able to change them in web.config if needed.